# Adding Mac-specific directory to PATH when home is shared

Tags: command-line, path

My /home/myusername/ directory is provided through a network, and looks exactly the same on my Linux machine and my Mac Mini.   I'd like to add to PATH a directory of Mac-specific software in my home, e.g. /home/myusername/SW/bin_mac/ and have this happen only when I'm doing command line stuff on the Mac, and not have PATH contain this when on Linux.  If I edit .bashrc (or tcsh's equivalent) it'll affect PATH in both cases.  What are some tricks to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Test the output of `uname`; it will be `Darwin` on OS X and `Linux` on Linux.

```
if [[ $(uname) == Darwin ]]; then
    export PATH="$HOME/SW/bin_mac:$PATH"
fi
```

Alternately, you could just add an appropriate directory on each machine, which will be useful if you find yourself needing a separate Linux `bin` directory as well in the future.

```
export PATH="$HOME/SW/bin_$(uname):..."
```

and either `mv` or `ln -s` your `bin_mac` to `bin_Darwin`; then you can create a `bin_Linux` directory in the future if you need it, and it'll just work.

(You could also test `$HOSTTYPE`, which is set by `bash`, but it contains more information than you're likely to need.)

Comment: The second solution looks great - a tidy one liner, and yes I may need to deal with multiple platforms and more than just PATH.